# Laravel and Transaction , okay to catch errors?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, transactions

I have a transaction like so :

```
return DB::transaction(function() use($intersectedArray,$user,$currentTime) {
            try {
                foreach ($intersectedArray as $subItemId) {
                    $user->todoSubItems()->updateExistingPivot($subItemId, ["done" => 1]);
                }
            }
            catch (Exception $e){
                return response()->json(500);
            }

            return response()->json($intersectedArray, 200);
        });
```

first of all , is it okay to run a loop inside like that ?(If a single query fails to update , I want the entire transaction to be rolled back.

2ndly , will the transaction still roll back even if I catch the error inside like that ?or will that prevent the transaction from working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll want to do `DB::rollBack();` before returning the 500 error.

Transactions get rolled back only if an uncaught exception is encountered. As you're catching the exception, it won't rollback unless you do so explicitly.